# How to get Invoked method name in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a code like this;

```
class abc{
    void A()
    {
        //Some to do statements
    }
    void B()
    {
        var obj=A();
    }
    void C()
    {
        var call=B();
    }
}
```

I want to find the Invoked method name using roslyn.

like here o/p will be:

- for method B :Invoked method A
- for method C:Invoked method A

i want something like this:

```
root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().Where(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals(methodName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

but InvocationExpression doesn't contain Identifier to access.
How to get identifier name

Comment: What about invocations like `Class.Method()` or `someDelegateField()` or `new SomeClass()` or `someDelegateArray[5]()`?

Comment: Is it relevant that the code you posted is wrong in many ways? You call void methods and assign the result as a value, for example.

Comment: I know my code is wrong. I have a just typed an example to define my scenario. actually i want the Invocation expression which are the methods defined in class that actually invoked by other method

Answer (score 17):

I agree with SLaks and would add to his answer, if what you want is:

"I want the method invocation syntax nodes where the receiver syntax -- let me emphasize SYNTAX -- is a single identifier equal to some particular string"

then the query you want is something like

```
var root = tree.GetRoot();
var nodes = from node in root.DescendantNodes()
                         .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
            let id = node.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax
            where id != null
            where id.Identifier.ValueText == methodName
            select node;
```

But I think that is maybe not what you want. If what you want is "I want to know exactly which method is invoked regardless of whether it is written `A(...)` or `Foo.Bar.A(...)` then you don't want to be considering the *syntax* at all. You'll need to use the semantic analyzer to get the *symbol* associated with the invocation, and then check whether that symbol identifies the method you're interested in.

Are you primarily interested in a *syntactic* or a *semantic* analysis here? Roslyn does either, but you're only looking at syntax in the code you've presented.

If what you're looking for is a semantic analysis then you want to do something like this:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var c = CSharpCompilation.Create("asm.dll");
c = c.AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
var model = c.GetSemanticModel(tree);
string methodName = "A";

var root = tree.GetRoot();
var symbols = from node in root.DescendantNodes()
                           .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
            let symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node.Expression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol
            where symbol != null
            where symbol.Name = methodName
            select symbol;
```

Comment: `where id?.Identifier.ValueText == methodName` :)

Comment: what is "r" here?

Answer (score 4):

The reason InvocationExpressionSyntax does not have Identifier because it may have with this case `var obj = this.A()` so it's reason why InvocationExpressionSyntax will contain property Expression with type ExpressionSyntax (which may be IdentifierNameSyntax type),

1.So simple answer for your case is you can access property Expression like this.

```
foreach (var item in root.DescendantNodes()
.OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>())
             {
                var expr = item.Expression;
                if (expr is IdentifierNameSyntax)
                {
                    IdentifierNameSyntax identifierName = r as IdentifierNameSyntax; // identifierName is your method name
                }

                if (expr is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)
                {
                    MemberAccessExpressionSyntax memberAccessExpressionSyntax = r as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
                    //memberAccessExpressionSyntax.Name is your method name
                }
            }
```

2.but for exact lookup the invocation method is the same with method you declared you have to use Semantic information as in this example in Roslyn project
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-find-all-calls-in-a-compilation-into-a-particular-namespace

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the role of these nodes in the syntax tree.

You should use the Roslyn Syntax Visualizer in VS to see what the nodes for a method call actually look like.

In short: An `InvocationExpression` just means `someExpression(some arguments)`.  That expression can be a number of things, such as a constructor call, a member access, an array access, or any other expression that resolves to a method or delegate.
You need to check the `Kind` of the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` and figure out how you want to handle every possible expression.

Comment: I believe invocation expressions and object creation expressions (constructor calls) are distinct.